# error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class ATL:: CTraceCategory

Tags: c++, atl, lnk2001

I got the same error as per this post below.

[error LNK2001](http://www.progtown.com/topic62210-errors.html)

someone replied "ATL uses ATLTRACE at debag-compilation. atlbase.h."
What does this mean? Do I have to add atlbase.h to my dependency?

Comment: It would help if you (a) showed some code, and (b) changed the `alt` tag to `atl`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add atls.lib (for release configuration) or atlsd.lib ( for debug configuration) in your linker dependencies.

```
Right click your project -> Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies
```

There atls.lib (for release configuration) or atlsd.lib ( for debug configuration) needs to be listed.

Comment: Hi, I have added atls.lib to the dependency for my release mode and still getting the error.